# Bigquery How to Set Labels

Tags: google-bigquery, looker

I want to set labels on my query so it will be easy to measure cost at our end so my query looks like this :

```
SET @@query_label = "ims:pricing_dashboard";
SELECT * FROM `my_bigquery_table` LIMIT 1000;
```

Since it's script and all my query are coming from Looker so i can't use the SQL like this ? How  i can change my query so i can set `query_label` and sql will return the result only

Comment: Hi @Marcin\_S, Can you check this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adding-labels). Might this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

On Looker: Edit your database connection > Additional Settings > Additional JDBC parameters

You can add labels to the BigQuery Jobs associated with the LookML components by using JBDC params.

See Looker Google BigQuery Docs, section [Job labels and context comments for BigQuery connections](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/db-config-google-bigquery#job_labels_and_context_comments_for_bigquery_connections)